# way to get the legends associated with the chart object in dojo

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo

I want to download a chart along with its legends as a pdf file.Is there any way to get the legends associated with a chart using the chart instance in Dojo charting. I googled a lot about this, but hardly found any solution.

Comment: could you provide an example ? do you want to extract the legend from dojo as a pdf file OR do you want to implement such a function ?

Comment: Have you also include the attribute `htmlLabels: false` on your legend so that the created svg would include legend as well?